# Are there any API's that can get the average price for a product?

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, price, google-shopping

I'm trying to make a web site that needs to frequently change the price of the product to the current market price so that I can order it and buy it for that price. Basically I'm just wondering if there's any API out there that can take the average of different website's prices for one product and give me an average so I can get the general price of that product.

Does Google shopping have something like this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *Is there a google shopping API that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Real-Time Product Search API](https://rapidapi.com/letscrape-6bRBa3QguO5/api/real-time-product-search) on RapidAPI to search for products on Google Shopping: each product in the response includes a "typical_price_range" field which which you can use to calculate the average price for products across the web:

```
"typical_price_range": [
    "$11",
    "$13"
]
```

Now, calculate the average of the lower and the higher end to get the average price for that product across the web. In our example, the average product price across the web is ($11 + $13) / 2 = **$12**.

**More details:**

As suggested by Chris, Google Shopping is a good fit for the task since it aggregates products from different websites across the web and already have this data available and ready to use.

Here is an example for the product "Typical prices across the web" feature on Google Shopping (see bottom-right corner):
[image]

Note: I am the creator of the Real-Time Product Search API on RapidAPI.